# Can't mount old drive due to mount point name conflict?

Tags: partitioning, mount, external-hdd, disk

My trusty Linux PC finally died today.  I immediately installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a new PC.  I then put the old Linux hard disk in an external USB external enclosure so I could copy my old files on to my new system.

Unfortunately I used the same user name when installing Ubuntu on the new PC.  When I power up the external drive and Linux tries to mount it, it fails saying that the name for the mount point directory Linux is already in use, that name being `/media/my_user_name`.

This makes sense because `/media/my_user_name` exists both on my new main drive and the external USB drive since both installs were done with the same user name.

Is there a way to tell Linux to mount the external USB drive with an alias, or some other method that would allow me to safely mount the external USB drive and avoid the current name conflict?  Unfortunately, as things stand now I can't access the drive and I really need to.

Comment: Why would you do a fresh install of 14.04 ? Why not 16.04 ? `sudo mkdir /media/old_drive && sudo mount /dev/old_hard_drive /media/old_drive` or some such will likely work. 16.04 will not mount if /media any longer, the default mount location changed.

Comment: Maybe the following link will give you some useful tips how to create a mountpoint (from scratch) in the new system's `/etc/fstab`, https://askubuntu.com/questions/962318/mount-usb-with-exec-flag-by-default/962323#962323