# Ububtu 18.04.1 USB 3.0 works with external drive but not flash drive

Tags: usb, exfat

I have a new clean install of 18.04.01 on hardware that was running Fedora 29 just fine. I had trouble with the iommu settings causing the usb ports to not work at all. Not even mouse and keyboard. Resolved that except that the usb 3.0 ports seem cranky. I have a Kingwin dock with a 1 terrabyte drive plugged into a USB 3.0 port that works just fine. It comes up in drive folder and mounts OK and I can access the entire drive. But then I connect a Samsung 64 gig 3.0 flash drive and it comes up but I get an error "Unknown file system exfat".
I tried this with a Sandisk 3.0 flash drive and got the same error. I tried both drives in the same port that the Kingwin was plugged into.  Very erratic behaviour.
I tried apt-get install extfat-fuse extfat-utils no errors. I rebooted but the weird behaviour continues.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The error "Unknown file system exfat" is about the file system, not about USB 3.

There are two ways to go,

- Work around the problem by replacing the Microsoft proprietary file system `exfat` with another Microsoft file system, `FAT32` or NTFS, or with the linux file system `ext4` or with UDF.
- Add the software necessary to manage the `exfat` file system. In my Lubuntu 18.04.1 LTS I have installed two program packages from the repository 'universe', which is there in installed Ubuntu systems,

  ```
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
  ```

[This AskUbuntu link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/952673/how-do-i-copy-a-file-larger-than-4gb-to-a-usb-flash-drive/952706#952706) will add some details about `exfat` and available alternatives.

---

Maybe there are problems with **mounting** the drive. In that case maybe [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/962318/mount-usb-with-exec-flag-by-default/962323#962323) may help.